# ARMv7 assembly store values in an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, armv7

I'm trying to add a user inputted number to a every element in an array.  I had everything working until I realized that the original array was not being updated.  Simple, I thought, just store the value back into the array and move on with life.  Sadly, this doesn't seem to be quite so simple.

As the title suggests, I'm using ARMv7 and writing assembly.  I've been using [this guide](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/27/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-8/) to understand the basics and to have some good code to look at.  When I run the example code given here it works fine: `str r2, [r3]` puts whatever is in `r2` into what `r3` points at.  The following is my attempt to do the same thing which gives me a `Signal 11 occurred: SIGSEGV (Invalid memory segment access)` and `Execution stopped at: 0x0000580C    STR    r3,[r5,#0]`:

```
@ Loop and add value to all values in array regardless of array length
@ Setup loop
@ r4 comes from above and the scanf value, I've checked the registers and the value is correct
mov     r0, #0
ldr     r1, =array_b
ldr     r2, addrArr
loop:                   @ Start loop to add inputed number to every value in array
    add     r3, r2, r0
    ldr     r3, [r3]
    add     r3, r3, r4  @ Add input to each index in array

    add     r5, r2, r0  @ Pointer to location in array
    str     r3, [r5]    @ Put new value into array

    cmp     r0, r1      @ Check for end of array
    addne   r0, r0, #4  @ Not super necessary but it shows one of the cool things ARM can do, condition math
    bne     loop        @ Branch if not equal
    beq     doneLoop    @ Branch if equal

doneLoop:               @ End loop
```

Here are the vars

```
.align  2
array:
    .word   0
    .word   1
    .word   2
    .word   3
    .word   4
    .word   5
    .word   6
    .word   7
.equ    array_b, .-array
addrArr:    .word array
```

My understanding is that `str` takes the source first and the destination second (which is different from other instructions for some reason).  So `r5` is used to calculate where in the array to store the value and `r3` has the value from the `add` instruction.  I've checked and the value in `r5` is valid, ie: it's the start of the array and the array_b is the proper length (32 in this case).  I've also tried doing `=array` instead of `addrArr` but they give the same value and the same segfault message.

Comment: Also, your code is horribly bloated. I know it's not your problem but I can't refrain from pointing it out. There is no need to do the addition of the base adress of your array and the index in every time, just do it once. Using the correct addressing modes, you don't even need to do it once, it is done automatically by the processor. Your loop should probably fit in 4 instructions. Finally, the last `beq` instruction does nothing.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, I'd love to know better ways to do this!  Could you provide a quick example or a link to somewhere that talks about this?

Comment: Yes, [this page](ftp://www.cs.uregina.ca/pub/class/301/ARM-addressing/lecture.html) appears to be a fairly good reference on what the ARM can do for addressing modes, among other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is historically in systems two major kind of memories :

- ROM, Read Only Memory, cannot be written to and can store only the program and constant data
- RAM, Random Access Memory, can be both read and written to. It is used to store variables.

Many systems do no use ROM directly, instead the data can be loaded from an other permanent support, for example a floppy disc, a tape or a hard disc into RAM. In order to avoid a program writing to RAM memory that wasn't supposed to be written, the RAM can be divided in multiple areas, using *segmented memory*.

Not all system features this, so it really depends on the architecture. If segmented memory is used, it basically makes the processor quit the application when you try to write to a segment of RAM that is designed to be read only. This is exactly what appears to be your problem here.

In order to solve this you should declare your array, which is a variable and should be stocked in RAM, by precedding it by `.data`.

On the other hand your executable instructions should be placed in the read only segment marked with the assembler directive `.text`

Comment: gcc puts code in `.rodata`?  Why would I use `.text` over `.rodata`?

Comment: Segments are described in the *linker script*, whose role is to say the linker which sections goes where in the address space. I suspect gcc separates `.rodata` is separated from `.text` to separate code and constant data, but I am not entierely sure so I could be wrong here. This could prevent you from erroneously execute constant data as code if the segmented pages support this feature. [Here is](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/scripts.html) what appears to be a good reference for linker script usage.